# Nrf24l01 module works on breadboard but not on pcb

Tags: pcb-design, communication, wireless

[image: Breadboard with bluetooth]After using a breadboarded nrf24l01 for more than a year, I decided to shrink it and have it on a pcb using the wiring diagram exactly used in the breadboard. I am attaching the pictures of the first and second breadboarded versions.

Both are working up till today. The third is the pcb mounted one.
My problem is that the reception range of the pcb mounted nrf2eounted on a pcb. Why has this happened?

I am just a tinkerer, no electrical or electronic background at all.

I am using an arduino nano as the mcu.
both are performing well and give me around 10 meters which is all I need 
really.

[This is the first breadboard version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgTmfm.jpg)
[image: This is the second breadboard version.]

But when I mounted same on a pcb, 
the range dropped to less than a meter.
[image: pcb mounted version]

Why is there a difference in receiver performance?

Comment: Is that a bluetooth module it is sitting next to?  If so, what have you done to de-conflict frequency usage in the 2.4 GHz band?  You should show the board layers in your question, particularly any copper pours.  Also, swap one of the modules between the breadboard and PCB setup.

Comment: Indeed it is a bluetooth. But even without the bluetooth, the range was still less than a meter.

Comment: The breadboard and PCB seem to use different versions of NRF PCBs. Are you sure you didn't miss something when designing the PCB version? Or maybe it uses a different (clone) chip?

Comment: Bigger module on the first picture is the regular nrf24l01 and the other one below is the mini. Both have the same range on the breadboard. Reason why I tried to mount the smaller one on a pcb to shrink the footprint. Then the problem began.. seems that I now understand the reason thanks to Nick Alexeev below. I gerry rigged another one outside of the ground plain and I gained more than five meters in range.

Answer (score 1):

Wireless modules with a built-in antenna are intended to be mounted such that the antenna sits on the corner or on the edge of the PCB.  You have placed the module in the middle of the PCB, and the metal in the PCB obstructs the antenna.

The datasheets for modules which have a built-in antenna usually have a recommended PCB layout.  (For example, p.10 in [this datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/50002279B-846406.pdf) or p.23 in [this datasheet](https://cdn.anaren.com/product-documents/AIR/WirelessAudio/A8520E24A91/A8520E24A91_UserManual.pdf).)

Your breadboard design didn't obstruct the antenna, so it had a better range.

Comment: One would still expect more than a meter range.  It's likely something else is wrong as well.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and move the module in such a way that the antenna protrude from the pcb.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I tried another one outside the ground plane and it gave me more than 5 meters more in range. I understand now what tuning the antenna is all about. Again thank you.